# R equivalent of "hold on" for plotting maps

Tags: r, maps

I want to add different colors to different states in the US. 
However when I run all my `map("state",."insert coloring condition"...)` commands sequentially, I don't get an overlay plot, it just updates the map but does not keep the coloring (as expected). When plotting graps you have acces to `lines()` and `points()` but it doesn't work with maps.. 
So how do I do that?

Comment: Isn't there an `add` argument to `map`?

Comment: @joran -- you are correct.  That should probably be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you read the documentation for `?map` you'll see that there is an `add` argument:

```
logical flag that specifies whether to add to the current plot. 
If FALSE, a new plot is begun, and a new coordinate system is set up.
```

that should do what you describe.

Comment: To add a full example: `map("state"); map("state", region = c("new york"),fill=TRUE,col="pink",add=TRUE);`